# $xy'-2y=\frac{x^6}{y+x^2}$ variation of parameters?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Information
$$xy'-2y=\dfrac{x^6}{y+x^2}.$$ Use variation of parameters followed by separation
of variables.

I have tried using $v=y+x^2$ but couldn't do anything.

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1|125.9131). It's time you start improving your questions, or you will soon be banned from asking questions.

Comment: It's $v=y/x^2$ not $v=y+x^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$xy'-2y=\dfrac{x^6}{y+x^2} \implies \displaystyle y'- \frac{2y}{x}=\dfrac{x^5}{y+x^2}$ ...(i)

LHS form is $y' + f(x)y = g(x)$ which is first order linear ODE and you should be using an integrating factor which is found using

$I = \displaystyle e^{\int f(x)dx} = e^{\int \frac{-2}{x}dx} = e^{-2 \, lnx} =  \frac{1}{x^2}$.

Using integrating factor in (i),

$\displaystyle \frac{y'}{x^2} - \frac{2y}{x^3}= \dfrac{x^3}{y+x^2}$

$\implies \displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}({\frac{y}{x^2}}) = \dfrac{x}{(y/x^2)+1}$

Substituting $u = \frac{y}{x^2}$,

$\frac{du}{dx} = \dfrac{x}{1 + u} \implies (1+u)du = xdx$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: isn't  $e^{-2lnx}=\frac{1}{x^2}$

Comment: how does $\frac{\frac{dy}{dx}}{x^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{y}{x^2}$ work

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx} (\frac{y}{x^2}) = \frac{1}{x^2} \frac{dy}{dx} - \frac{2}{x^3}y$.

Comment: @ArmanTuran Pls note LHS has two parts.

Answer (score 1):

$$xy'-2y=\dfrac{x^6}{y+x^2}.$$
You can rewrite it as:
$$\left(\dfrac y {x^2}\right)'=\dfrac{x^3}{y+x^2}.$$
$$(y+x^2) \left(\dfrac y {x^2}\right)'={x^3}$$
It's separable:
$$\left(\dfrac y{x^2}+1 \right)\left(\dfrac y {x^2}\right)'=x$$
$$\left(\dfrac y{x^2}+1 \right)d\left(\dfrac y {x^2}\right)=xdx$$
Integrate both sides.