# Solving a differential equation using an integrating factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> I'm trying the solve the following equation: $ \left\{\begin{matrix}
> (x^B+y^B)(xdy-ydx)=(1+x)x^9dx \\  y(-1)=A \end{matrix}\right. $
>
> for $A=1$ and $A=0$.
>
> $B\in2\mathbb{N}_0+1$

My solution is the following, but I got stuck:

$(x^B+y^B)(xdy-ydx)=(1+x)*x^9dx$

$x^B*xdy-y*x^Bdx+y^B*xdy-y*y^Bdx-(1+x)*x^9dx=0$

$x^B*xdy+y^B*xdy-y*x^Bdx-y*y^Bdx-(1+x)*x^9dx=0$

$xdy(x^B+y^B)+[-y(x^B+y^B)-(1+x)*x^9]dx=0$

where:

$Q(x,y)=x(x^B+y^B)dy$

$P(x,y)=[-y(x^B+y^B)-(1+x)*x^9]$

Then I made partial derivation:

$\frac{∂Q}{∂x}:(x^B+y^B)x(Bx^{B-1})$

$\frac{∂P}{∂y}: -(x^B+y^B)-y(By^{B-1})$

And then subtract:

$\frac{∂P}{∂y}-\frac{∂Q}{∂x}=-(x^B+y^B)-y(By^{B-1})-(x^B+y^B)-x(Bx^{B-1})$

But probably I did something wrong and
I'm stuck and not sure where made I mistake.. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(x^B+y^B)(xdy-ydx)=(1+x)x^9dx$

$xdy-ydx = \frac{(1+x)x^9}{(x^B+y^B)}dx$

$x \frac{dy}{dx} - y = \frac{(1+x)x^9}{(x^B+y^B)}$

$\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx} - \frac{y}{x} = \frac{(1+x)x^8}{(x^B+y^B)}$

Based on the form of LHS, take integrating factor of $ \displaystyle \frac{1}{x}$.

$\displaystyle \frac {1}{x} \frac{dy}{dx}- \frac{y}{x^2} = \frac{(1+x)x^7}{(x^B+y^B)}$

$\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx} (\frac{y}{x}) = \frac{(1+x)x^{(7-B)}}{1+ (\frac{y}{x})^B}$

Substitute $u = \frac{y}{x}$

$\displaystyle ({1+ u^B}) du = ((1+x)x^{(7-B)}) dx$

Can you please take it from here?

Comment: Can you please show me how you write it in this form? $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx} - \frac{y}{x} = \frac{(1+x)x^8}{(x^B+y^B)}$

Comment: @PeterF. I edited.

Comment: Thank you, but I do not understand, how you take integrating factor..

Comment: See if my answer a while ago helps https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3879604/xy-2y-fracx6yx2-variation-of-parameters/3879666#3879666.

Comment: Thanks it is more clear, but I thought that I shoult do integrating factor by following one of the principle on this site https://www.math24.net/using-integrating-factor/ ,,, I was just trying to do it in this way

Comment: Oh, I understand,, thank you so much..

Comment: @PeterF. you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

$$(x^B+y^B)(xdy-ydx)=(1+x)x^9dx $$
Duivide by $x^2$:
$$(x^B+y^B)d\dfrac yx=(1+x)x^7dx $$
Divode by $x^B$:
$$\left(1+\left(\dfrac y x\right)^B \right)d\dfrac yx=\dfrac {(1+x)x^7}{x^B}dx $$
Integrate.